# If $g(x) = 2f(x) + 5$, find the value of $g^{-1}(x)$ [inverse]. Considering $f(x)$ is invertible

Tags: functions

I know that when an invertible function is inverted, the domain becomes the range and viceversa.
That implies,
Value of g(inverse) = Domain of g(x) = 2(Range of f(x)) +5 
So my answer would be 2(f(inverse)(x)) + 5 which is incorrect. I would like to know why

Comment: Suppose $f(x)=x$. Then the inverse of $f(x)$ is just $f(x)$. So you think $2x+5$ is the inverse of $2x+5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=g(x)$ then $y=2 f(x)+5$ and so $f(x) = {1 \over 2} (y-5)$ and so
$x = g^{-1}(y) = f^{-1} ({1 \over 2} (y-5))$.

Hence $g^{-1}(y) = f^{-1} ({1 \over 2} (y-5)$.

Comment: How did you reach the last step? I understood till the value of x.

Comment: If $f(x) = z$ then since $f$ is invertible, then $x = f^{-1}(z)$.

Comment: I meant the value of g inverse

Comment: The first line shows a formula for $x = g^{-1}(y)$. The second line just replaces the symbol $y$ by $x$.

Comment: I have changed the symbols to reduce confusion & delay.

Answer (score 1):

Solve $y=2f(x)+5$ for $x$, $f(x)=(y-5)/2$ so $x=f^{-1}((y-5)/2)$.
So $g^{-1}(x)=f^{-1}((x-5)/2)$

Comment: How did you reach the last step? I understood till the value of x.

Comment: @PrabhdeepSingh Usually the way you do this is to solve for $x$ and then switch $x$ and $y$ so that $x$ is the domain variable.  But that's just a convention, it's really not strictly necessary you could leave the answer in terms of $y$.